# Where to post a question about blogging software?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask a question about a blogging software for our dev team. Should it go to:

- StackOverflow because the blogging software will be used as part of our development process?
- ServerFault as this is about the server-side software?
- SuperUser as blogging engines are standard applications in many ways?

I think it is partly appropriate for all 3 sites, and partly inappropriate at the same time. You could argue that it depends on the exact character of the question and you'd be right but still, there are quite a few cases where the question is partly appropriate for at least 2 of the sites. How should I handle such questions?

(Personally, I find this overlap unpleasant. It "makes me think" which is not good.)

Comment: related or duplicate, I am not sure - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44513/questions-about-wordpress-on-super-user

Comment: Certainly related. Also a candidate for the Stack Exchange 2.0 - http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0

Answer (score 1):

There's no good place for that topic right now.

But there might be.. soon-ish.

See:
http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0

Comment: As long as there is a single form that will automatically decide from the contents of the question where it should go, it's fine with me :)

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking too much. You're thinking about "blogging questions" generally, while you should be thinking about your specific question in isolation.

Is the question you're asking about writing blogging software? Stack Overflow.

Furthermore, is the question about configuring a common server-side blogging package? Server Fault (I think).

Finally, is the question about blogging in general? GTFO.

Comment: there are some proposals for some sites.. I'll email you

Comment: @Jeff: You're a pretty weird guy, you know that?

Comment: "I think" from your answer: that's exactly the problem. Sometimes, it's not clear where to post the question (far too often for the questions I'd like to ask).

Comment: Where should I post about posts about where posts should do?